# Adding WCF service reference

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core

in .net core we are trying to add wcf service reference and show us TLS SSL issue. Would it be possible that if the end point is requiring credentials?

from connected service > chose wcf to add > add the URI (ends with .svc) > keeping all defaults in next pages, clicking on finish shows below message. there is no other details.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xfbO.png)

Comment: I am not sure what is being asked here could you add some examples or code to describe your problem? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help

Comment: added error screen shot

Comment: Can you access the url in some other way and download the XML to a file? You can use this XML file to add a WCF service reference.

Answer (score 0):

This typically indicates that the server uses SSL certificates to protect its communication, and does not explicitly require the client to provide a certificate for authentication.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/working-with-certificates
In the SSL communication process, a trust relationship needs to be established. Therefore, the client needs to have the necessary conditions to establish SSL communication. When adding service references on the client-side, the server's WSDL will be downloaded and used. During this process, please trust the server certificate and ensure that TLS communication is supported on the client-side.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
Besides, I advise you get the WSDL file by browser first. Likewise, this also requires the above. After establishing the trust relationship, the browser address bar should have a secure lock flag. Subsequently, try it again in the `Adding service reference` dialog.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for the details. When I tried to browse service url, it went through ssl communication step and then asking for username password. It seems like it needs Authentication before serving. Thanks again. this make sense now why VS studio could not create proxy classes.

Comment: the server-side enabled the windows authentication, please enter your windows credential and try it again. these credentials usually are the login account on the server-side.